# Proving that paired time series are (not) correlated

Tags: time-series, paired-data, controlling-for-a-variable, dyadic-data

I've got a dataset comprised of a bunch of "paired" time series, where the data in each part of the "pair" are dependent on each other, but I'm actually concerned with (dis)proving that the two time series in each pair are significantly more similar to each other than they are to all the other series in the dataset. How can I most easily do this, especially given that I want to control for the fact that the two time series are dependent? -- in other words, given series $S_{1,a}$, $S_{1,b}$, $S_{2,a}$ and $S_{1,b}$, how can I show that series $S_{i,a}$, $S_{i,b}$ are significantly more related for a given $i$ than for all other values of $i$?

To illustrate, I've got data of an experiment with two participants where, in each turn, each participant makes a set of observable choices *apple*, *banana*, *kumquat*, *orange*, *pear*, etc. I want to show that, all else being equal, not only is there (not) a trend of participants making choices similarly to their own previous choices but also there is (not) a separate trend of making choices similar to that of their partner's:

```
| Dyad | Participant | Timestep | Stimulus | Apple | Banana | Kumquat | Orange | Pear |
|------|-------------|----------|----------|-------|--------|---------|--------|------|
| 1    | A           | 1        | Red      | 1     | 0      | 0       | 0      | 1    |
| 1    | B           | 1        | Red      | 1     | 0      | 1       | 0      | 0    |
| 1    | A           | 2        | Blue     | 0     | 1      | 0       | 0      | 0    |
| 1    | B           | 2        | Blue     | 1     | 1      | 0       | 0      | 1    |
| 2    | A           | 1        | Yellow   | 1     | 0      | 0       | 1      | 0    |
| 2    | B           | 1        | Yellow   | 1     | 0      | 0       | 0      | 1    |
| 2    | A           | 2        | Red      | 0     | 1      | 0       | 0      | 1    |
| 2    | B           | 2        | Red      | 1     | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0    |
```

Moreover, I would like to control for any possible timestep-related effects, namely that e.g. for whatever reason, as timestep increases, the probability of choosing *kumquat* increases (e.g. just because it's a cool name and the participants haven't picked it yet so they feel they have to eventually).

**What sort of analysis best fits this problem?** Moreover, how should I best structure the data? — Would simply having one pair of observations `Apple_A` and `Apple_B` etc. be better than separating the data into individual datapoints, as shown above?

Comment: One approach would be to estimate an information theoretic metric such as mutual information, minimum distance or Kullback-Lieber divergence. These methods are momentless and distribution free, in other words, they are astatistical. Permutation distance methods for paired time series have been developed and are out there. One such is Andreas Brandmaier's PDC for permutation distance clustering. He has written several papers describing this methodology as well as an R module for implementation. E.g., https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i05/v067i05.pdf. His is not the only one

Comment: Thanks; that's some interesting info. However, it's a bit much just by itself: Do you mean to e.g. calculate mutual information of one datapoint's set of observations with that of the preceding datapoint, e.g. the mutual information for `Apple_{1,A,3}, Banana_{1,A,3}` etc. and `Apple_{1,A,2}, Banana_{1,A,2}` etc.?

Comment: This was a *hopefully* helpful suggestion based on your description of a time series. One reason you're not getting more in the way of a response from CV is, in my opinion, due to the very specific nature of your concern, as evidenced by your response to my suggestion. As much as anyone on CV, I understand how data works but I don't understand *your* data well enough to answer your very specific question and, frankly, I don't care to. The NLP literature on LDA may be another approach. see ... http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_blei_tm/

Comment: Interesting: on most SE sites I peruse, questions which are not "very specific" tend to get closed.